# symantec endpoint protection geo blocking

Tags: windows-server-2008, symantec-endpoint-protection

How can I create a firewall rule that will only allow RDP connections from my country (on specified port) ? All the rest will be blocked.
I am using Symantec Endpoint Protection 14.0  RU1 build 3929.1200.

Answer (score 0):

SEPM dont have country blocking. You have to do it manually by IP range.. or use a firewall appliance that will do it.

Please see there to upvote that suggested idea on Symantec (https://www-secure.symantec.com/connect/security/ideas) - [Advanced Firewall Settings](https://www.symantec.com/connect/idea/advanced-firewall-settings)